# Omitting text in between regex groups in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I'm looking to capture groups of matches via regex, but I want to omit what's in between the matches.

Sample string:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'name_lastt' in 'field list'
```

I'm trying to match **1054** and **name_lastt** (with or without single quotes)

My regex matcher is as follows:

```
$pattern = '/(1054)(?:.*(\'\w*\'))/';
```

I get very close, but I also get a weird, unexpected match at array index 0, as seen below:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1054 Unknown column 'name_lastt'
    [1] => 1054
    [2] => 'name_lastt'
)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `[0]` is the whole text match.`[1]` and `[2]` are the groups captured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

php preg match will add the whole text matched in the first index and then the other next

You can make array_shift($matches); to shift the first element of the array check manual here         http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php

Answer (score 0):

Use the below regex to get only the output you expected.

```
1054(?=.*(?:\'\w*\'))|(?<=1054)(?:.*\K(?:\'\w*\'))
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/cA7jY5/1)